# Spartan 6 pin output impedance

Tags: fpga, impedance, digital-communications, ibis

I'm trying to decide if the internal programmable output termination (UNTUNED_50) of the spartan **XC6SLX45-2CSG324I** if sufficient for our design, or an external termination is needed.

The traces from the fpga pin (driver) to the IC (receiver) are relative long ~30cm, so reflections will occur and be a problem without source termination.

I have looked at the IBIS model [spartan6 IBIS](https://www.xilinx.com/support/download/index.html/content/xilinx/en/downloadNav/device-models/ibis-models/spartan-series-fpgas.html) for the driver LVCMOS18_S_8_LR_33 the output termination resistance is calculated to: min=41, typ=50, max=64.
Which I would consider good.

But looking in the datasheet [ds162](https://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQ57WxqMbRAhXoNJoKHZXAB5IQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xilinx.com%2Fsupport%2Fdocumentation%2Fdata_sheets%2Fds162.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGjj7k41H-bm9rlLGcd5ZryVqk5oA&bvm=bv.144224172,d.bGs) on page 5, the UNTUNED_50 has very wide range 21 to 96 ohm, which would give significant ringing.

So two questions:

1. Why is there so big difference between the IBIS model, and the datasheet ?
2. When should I generally not use the internal output termination ?

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet values are across the recommended operating conditions (-40C to +100C Tj for industrial grade); IBIS models are usually at 25C and do not account for large variations in temperature.

This is a common issue in models, as the typical (not guaranteed) values are used.

If you expect to see a wide range of temperatures, use the values from the datasheet, as these are the only values that are *guaranteed* (if you have problems and used the IBIS values, Xilinx will not help you as those values are not guaranteed).

If you have a need for precise output terminations, then do not use the internal terminators.

Comment: According to the IBIS model the temperature range is 0 to 85 Celsius. Which would be a ok range. The IBIS model for the 2.5V is a lot worse than 1.8V, so could the big variation come from all supported voltages. ?

Comment: As the guaranteed range is across all operating conditions, then supported voltages will also have an effect.

Comment: Ok, so when using 1.8V LVCMOS and temperature range 0 to 85 Celsius, are my assumptions correct, that the output driver resistance is between 41 to 64 ohm ?